# woocommerce addtional information tab change Dimensions title

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

In product page, under additional information, I want to change the "Dimensions" to "Box Dimensions".

Also my measurements are in grams, but I want to display them to the end user in KG's is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done [overriding Woocommerce templates files via your active child theme (or theme)](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

If not done yet, you will have to create a folder "woocommerce" in your active child theme (or active theme). Then you will need to copy from: 
`wp-content/plugins/templates/single-product//product-attributes.php`
to your active child theme *(or active theme)* "woocommerce" folder: 
`single-product/product-attributes.php`

Then you will change this line:

```
        <th><?php _e( 'Dimensions', 'woocommerce' ) ?></th>
```

by this instead:

```
        <th><?php _e( 'Box Dimensions', 'woocommerce' ) ?></th>
```

---

**Changing displayed units:**

Then you can change the displayed unit in Woocommerce settings > Products > General:

[image]

Or you can use the following hooked function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'custom_format_dimensions', 20, 2 );
function custom_format_dimensions( $dimension_string, $dimensions ) {
    $dimension_string = implode( ' x ', array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $dimensions ) ) );

    if ( ! empty( $dimension_string ) ) 
        $dimension_string .= ' ' . __("KG", "woocommerce");
    else
        $dimension_string = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

    return $dimension_string;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.